# Inconsistent Results Using Loopback Count End-Point With Filter+Where vs. Just Where

Tags: rest, httprequest, loopbackjs, strongloop

We're getting unexpected and inconsistent results when using Loopback's **count** end-point. Using **filter[where]** always returns the total number of rows in the table, ignoring any filter. For example, the following call always returns a value of **9** which is not correct (given the data below):

```
/api/class/count?filter[where][companyrowid]=1
```

**Class Table Data (MySQL)**

```
rowid  description         companyrowid
3367   test1                0             
3366   test2                0             
3364   Asia Division        1             
3365   Australia Division   1             
3362   Canada Division      1             
3363   Europe Division      1             
3359   US East Division     1             
3361   US Midwest Division  1             
3360   US West Division     1
```

Strangely, using **'where[companyid]=1'** returns the **correct value of 7**. Close inspection of the http request object shows that **filter[where][...]** and **where[..]** filters are actually stored separately and yield different results:

```
/api/class/count?filter[where][companyrowid]=1
```

1. req.query.filter.where = {companyid: "1"}
2. req.query.where = undefined
3. Result: 9 (incorrect)

`/api/class/count?where[companyrowid]=1`

1. req.query.filter.where = undefined
2. req.query.where = {companyid: "1"}
3. Result: 7 (correct)

The biggest issue is the **filter[where]** ignoring the filter.

Comment: We're using Loopback v2.22.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

count() method only takes the where clause instead of the filter. 
So your REST API should be like this

```
/api/class/count?[where][companyrowid]=1
```

Comment: Why the inconsistency? Are there others that don't support filter?